# Script to transform C++ code to webassembly is not terminating

Tags: c++, webassembly

I want to compile a CPP file to web assembly. I am using scripts in the following link

https://github.com/wasdk/wasmexplorer-service/tree/master/scripts

I am using the following command in my Linux OS

../scripts/compile2.sh ../test.cpp "-fno-verbose-asm -03 -std=c++98" 2>&1

The command never terminates. I have tried all combinations of options. Can anyone guide me in this regard? Or any other way to transform C++ code to respective web assembly code (help me design a stand-alone application ).

Content of the  file is as follows:

```
double fact(int i) {
  long long n = 1;
  for (;i > 0; i--) {
    n *= i;
  }
  return (double)n;
}
```

My expected output is as following (is from https://mbebenita.github.io/WasmExplorer/)

```
(module
 (table 0 anyfunc)
 (memory $0 1)
 (export "memory" (memory $0))
 (export "_Z4facti" (func $_Z4facti))
 (func $_Z4facti (; 0 ;) (param $0 i32) (result f64)
  (local $1 i64)
  (local $2 i64)
  (block $label$0
   (br_if $label$0
    (i32.lt_s
     (get_local $0)
     (i32.const 1)
    )
   )
   (set_local $1
    (i64.add
     (i64.extend_s/i32
      (get_local $0)
     )
     (i64.const 1)
    )
   )
   (set_local $2
    (i64.const 1)
   )
   (loop $label$1
    (set_local $2
     (i64.mul
      (get_local $2)
      (tee_local $1
       (i64.add
        (get_local $1)
        (i64.const -1)
       )
      )
     )
    )
    (br_if $label$1
     (i64.gt_s
      (get_local $1)
      (i64.const 1)
     )
    )
   )
   (return
    (f64.convert_s/i64
     (get_local $2)
    )
   )
  )
  (f64.const 1)
 )
)
```

Comment: FYI, there is no language `C/C++`.  They are distinct languages.  For example, C++ has `std::string`, `std::vector`, inheritance, function overloading and operator overloading .  In C, I can have a variable called `private`, `class` or `namespace`.  You should make your life easier and stick to one language.  Mixing the languages adds complexity to your program, which increases the probability of injecting defects.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

running the following code works for me

```
/*
# run me with 'bash test.cpp'
clang++ $0 --target=wasm32-unknown-unknown-wasm -nostartfiles -nostdlib -Wl,--no-entry -Wl,--export-all -o test.wasm

exit 1
*/

extern "C" double fact(int i) {
  long long n = 1;
  for (;i > 0; i--) {
    n *= i;
  }
  return (double)n;
}
```

testing with

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script type="module">
  async function init() {
    const { instance } = await WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(fetch("./test.wasm"));
    console.log(instance.exports.fact(6));
  }
  init();
</script>
```